# Detect when an iframe is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Currently, my website is being embedded inside another website. But the problem is I want to know when my iframe is shown, so that can do some script.

Something similar to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <iframe id="page1">
       <!-- MY PAGE 1 CODE GOES HERE-->
  </iframe>
  <iframe id="page2">
       <!-- MY PAGE 2 CODE GOES HERE-->
  </iframe>
  <iframe id="page3">
       <!-- MY PAGE 3 CODE GOES HERE-->
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The problem here, the wrapper load all of my embeded code at the same time, then hide all and show only one. Then when user interact, it'll show another pages.

My problem is: I need to know when the wrapper show my page 1/page 2/page 3 code so that can do further process.

Hope to receive some hints.

@edited 2014-02-15: 
My code is being used by the wrapper's owner. You can think of it as a plugin content for them.

The wrapper used display:none to hide or show the iframe which wrap my content.

Comment: Post relevant code which show/hide a specific iframe

Comment: If the main page has not [the same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) with your page, I'm afraid you can't find out the visibility of your page.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've edited my question to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Teemu they are in the same domain, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on, how an iframe is made invisible. If `display: none` is used, a simple way to detect the visibility of an iframe *in iframe* is:

```
var isVisible = !!window.frameElement.offsetWidth; // --> true or false
```

`offsetWidth` equals to `0`, when `display` is set to `none` in an iframe or one of its parent elements.

Comment: Thank to your help. Looks like it worked now and I can detect whether the iframe were hide on the load or not. Then the next problem is how to know when the frame is set to visible again, do you know how to do that?

Comment: `isVisible` in my answer equals to `true`, if the iframe has a width... You're setting the visibility with JS, just change a variable within iframe in the same code?

Comment: It's a bit different in my case. So I've used a timer to loop and wait for the frame to change its visibility. It works for now. Thank you.